# Is there a website like etherscripter.com, for Solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, serpent

Is there a Scratch website available for the Solidity language? The only one I could find was Etherscripter.com however that one is only for Serpent.

Comment: Etherscripter is based on Google's Blockly; it'd be fairly straightforward in principle to build a similar version for Solidity - Blockly is explicitly designed to make building new backends straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

There is browser solidity, which allows you to compile but does not seem to include the full functionality of EtherScripter: http://chriseth.github.io/browser-solidity/

Comment: Browser solidity has nothing in common with Etherscripter as far as I know it's not a visual editor like requested in this question. However the best thing would be to implement solidity in Etherscripter. But I can't find any way to contact the author, no guthub project and even whois is not helpful.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the differences. I'll leave the answer because it is the only browser-based compiler for solidity that I know. However, you don't need to mark it as correct and maybe you'll get more answers. ☺️

Comment: @tayvano I was aware of that site, however it was not what I was looking for.

Comment: @Jeth -- here's the guys announcement post: https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/713/etherscripter-a-visual-smart-contract-builder and his github is here: https://github.com/mode80 (although the etherscripter source is not)

Comment: @tayvano thanks for the links.If anyone knows mode80 or a way to contact him, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

ArabianChain is developing one using blockly as well and it'll cover Solidity, Serpent and Thuraya.
It'll be ready in June 2017.

this is a pre-launch video , not that attractive yet but it'll show the builder.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbaZ6f4AFhs